# Subtructing n number of columns from two files with AWK

Tags: linux, perl, bash, awk, gawk

I have two files with N number of columns

File1:

```
A   1   2    3  .......  Na1
B   2   3    4  .......  Nb1
```

File2:

```
A   2   2    4  .......  Na2
B   1   3    4  .......  Nb2
```

i want a output where 1st column value from File1 will be subtracted from 1st column of File2, and this way till column N as shown below:

```
A  -1   0    -1  ........ (Na1-Na2)
B   1   0     0  ........ (Nb1-Nb2)
```

How to do this is AWK, or Perl scripting in Linux environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@fh, @v);
for (@ARGV) {
  open (my $handle, "<", $_) or die ("$!: $_");
  push @fh, $handle;
}
while (@v = map { [split ' ', <$_> ] } @fh and defined shift @{$v[0]}) {
  print join(" ", (shift @{$v[1]}, map { $_ - shift(@{$v[1]}) } @{$v[0]})), "\n";
}
close $_ for (@fh);
```

To run:

```
 perl script.pl input1 input2
```

Comment: Always put `$!` in the `die` string so you know *why* the open failed. `split ' '` is almost always what you want, rather than `split /\s+/`. The C-style `for` loop is usually better written as a list iterator, here `for my $i (0 .. $#v2) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered, but I will add a one-liner. It uses `paste`, to concatenate the files, and `awk` to subtract:

```
paste file{1,2} | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF/2;i++) printf "%s ", ($i==$i+0)?$i-$(i+NF/2):$i; print ""}'
```

Validation:

```
$ cat file1
A   1   2    3   4  5
B   2   3    4   5  6

$ cat file2
A   2   2    4 10 12 
B   1   3    4  3 5

$ paste file{1,2} | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF/2;i++) printf "%s ", ($i==$i+0)?$i-$(i+NF/2):$i; print ""}'
A -1 0 -1 -6 -7 
B 1 0 0 2 1
```

It requires both files to have the same number of columns. Non-numeric columns should be at the same position. It prints the value in the first file if non-numeric, otherwise prints the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk '{split($0,S); getline<f; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i-=S[i]}1' OFS='\t' f=file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk File2 File1 | rev | column -t | rev
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[$1][i]=$i
    }
    next
}

{
    for(j=2;j<=NF;j++) {
        $j-=a[$1][j]
    }
}1
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1][i]=$i; next } { for(j=2;j<=NF;j++) $j-=a[$1][j] }1' File2 File1 | rev | column -t | rev
```

Results:

```
A  -1  0  -1
B   1  0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[FNR"-"i]=$i;next}{printf "\n"$1" ";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf $i-a[FNR"-"i]" "}}' file1 file2
> cat file1
A   1   2    3
B   2   3    4
> cat file2
A   2   2    4
B   1   3    4
> awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[FNR"-"i]=$i;next}{printf "\n"$1" ";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf $i-a[FNR"-"i]" "}}' file1 file2 
A 1 0 1 
B -1 0 0 
>
```

Alternatively put this in a file

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
FNR==NR{
   for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
   a[FNR"-"i]=$i;next
     }
   {
    printf "\n"$1" ";
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
    {
     printf $i-a[FNR"-"i]" "
    }
   }
```

and execute as:

```
awk -f file.awk file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps? I'm afraid I can't test this code as I have no PC to hand at present.

This program expects the names of the two files as parameters on the command line, and outputs the results to `STDOUT`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @fh;
for my $filename (@ARGV) {
  open my $fh, '<', $filename;
  push @fh, $fh;
}

until (grep eof $_, @fh) {
  my @records;
  for my $fh (@fh) {
    my $line = <$fh>;
    chomp $line;
    push @records, [ split ' ', $line ];
  }

  $records[0][$_] -= $records[1][$_] for 1 .. $#{$records[0]};
  print "@{$records[0]}\n";
}
```

Comment: The comma after `push` doesn't belong there :-)

Comment: @ChrisCharley: Don't know how that crept in! Thanks. Fixed.