# Get difference between two csv files based on column using bash

Tags: csv, awk

I have two csv files `a.csv` and `b.csv`, both of them come with no headers and each value in a row is seperated by `\t`.

```
1   apple
2   banana
3   orange
4   pear
```

```
apple   0.89
banana  0.57
cherry  0.34
```

I want to subtract these two files and get difference between the second column in `a.csv` and the first column in `b.csv`, something like `a.csv[1] - b.csv[0]` that would give me another file `c.csv` looks like

```
orange
pear
```

Instead of using python and other programming languages, I want to use **bash command** to complete this task and found out that `awk` would be helpful but not so sure how to write the correct command. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894702/subtract-columns-from-different-files-with-awk) is another similar question but the second answer uses `awk '{print $2,$6-$13}'` to get the difference between values instead of occurence.

Thanks and appreciate for any help.

Comment: Are you sure your expected output is fully showed ? I guess you missed `cherry` ?

Comment: @Zelnes: OP wants entries (second column) in the first file which are not present in second file (first column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with the [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894812/5291015) from the link you are referring to with a bit of tweak. Not sure the other answer with `paste` will get you solving this problem.

Create a hash-map from the second file `b.csv` and compare it again with the 2nd column in `a.csv`

```
awk -v FS="\t" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } FNR == NR { unique[$1]; next } !($2 in unique) { print $2 }' b.csv a.csv
```

To redirect the output to a new file, append `> c.csv` at the end of the previous command.

Set the field separators (input and output) to `\t` as you were reading a tab-delimited file.

1. The `FNR == NR { action; } { action } f1 f2` is a general construct you find in many `awk` commands that works if you had to do action on more than one file. The block right after the `FNR == NR` gets executed on the first file argument provided and the next block within `{..}` runs on the second file argument.
2. The part `unique[$1]; next` creates a hash-map `unique` with key as the value in the first column on the file `b.csv`. The part within `{..}` runs for all the columns in the file.
3. After this file is completely processed, on the next file `a.csv`, we do `!($2 in unique)` which means, mark those lines whose `$2` in the second file is not part of the key in the `unique` hash-map generated from the first file.
4. On these lines print only the second column names `{ print $2 }`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination, that's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your real data is sorted on the columns you care about like your sample data is:

```
$ comm -23 <(cut -f2 a.tsv) <(cut -f1 b.tsv)
orange
pear
```

This uses [comm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) to print out the entries in the first file that aren't in the second one, after using [cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) to get just the columns you care about.

If not already sorted:

```
comm -23 <(cut -f2 a.tsv | sort) <(cut -f1 b.tsv | sort)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), a clean and easy tool, the command could be

```
mlr --nidx --fs "\t" join --ul --np -j join -l 2 -r 1  -f 01.txt then cut -f 2 02.txt
```

It gives you

```
orange
pear
```

It's a [join](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-verbs.html#join) in which it does not emit paired records and emits unpaired records from the left file.

Comment: This is also helpful, I will look into that for other tasks.